# How To Display Date In Locale For 0 Values?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datetime, cultureinfo

Ok, so I have a date stored in UK format (dd/mm/yy) which I need to display in the locale of wherever the user might be.

The issue is that this date can be 000000 (00/00/2000); so I can't convert it to DateTime directly, as DateTime doesn't support 0 values for day or month.

I have this so far:

```
int dateInt = ddmmyy;
var year = (dateInt % 100) + 2000;
var month = (dateInt / 100) % 100;
var day = (dateInt / 100000);

var result = new DateTime(year, month, day); //2014/00/00 at this point, so breaks.

var resultStr = result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
return resultStr;
```

What's the correct way to add support for 0 values initially? I've tried changing the 0 to 1 before converting to DateTime, running the conversion and then replacing with a 0 again; but due to culture variants I see no way that this method can support other cultures, which is the purpose of this conversion to begin with.

Any ideas? I'm guessing this is a common issue.

Comment: How about if(ddmmyy==0)
   return new DateTime(2000,1,1);

After the first line

Comment: @GeorgeVovos This is just a one case. A general solution should provided..

Comment: @SonerGönül from what i understood only 000000 was the only invalid value

Comment: By the way, there is no `00` as month or day, but there is for year which depends on [`Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That's why doesn't support these values.

Comment: @user3420034 As I said, you can't parse `00` as month or day. One way could be split your string and check them (_month_ and _day_ part) as `00` and replace them with `01`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] savedDates = new int[] { 000000, 010000, 000013 };

        foreach (var item in savedDates)
        {
            DateTime date = ConvertToDate(item);
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString("D6") + " => " + date.ToShortDateString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static DateTime ConvertToDate(int item)
    {
        string temp = item.ToString("D6");
        int day = int.Parse(temp.Substring(0, 2));
        int month = int.Parse(temp.Substring(2, 2));
        int year = int.Parse(temp.Substring(4, 2));

        if (day == 0)
            day = 1;

        if (month == 0)
            month = 1;

        year += 2000;


        return new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not store dates like this as the methodology for doing so is already provided by the .NET framework.

The best way to store dates would be to use `Culture.InvariantCulture` for string conversion cases and then convert to local culture for display purposes as necessary. `DateTime` itself is culture-independent so converting between cultures is very easy.